# How can i see if an owner has permissions to execute a Store Procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, permissions, execute, sql-grant, owner

I need to validate if my owner has permissions to execute a store procedure,  but i have to do it searching on a sys table. In which table i can find it.

Thank you!!

Comment: loot at all_tab_privs

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to its name, DBA_TAB_PRIVS allows us to see granted privileges on all objects, not just table.

```
select * from DBA_TAB_PRIVS 
where type='PROCEDURE' 
and privilege='EXECUTE'
and OWNER='SCHEMANAME'
AND TABLE_NAME='PROCEDURENAME';
```

Comment: You might want to clarify that the `TABLE_NAME` in `DBA_TAB_PRIVS` will be the name of the stored procedure and that the `PRIVILEGE` in that table will be "EXECUTE".